# Mapping DNS name to my website which is hosted on azure Virtual machine

Tags: iis, azure, dns

How do i map my dns(www.mydomain.com) to my website which is hosted on my virtual machine.

Things i already done.

1. Created virtual machine in Azure.
2. Added endpoint on public port 80, private port 80
3. Website hosted on IIS, and can access via localhost (inside virtual machine) and even via http:// ipaddress/sitename/ (outside of virtual machine)
4. I already have a DNS name in godaddy.

Also if i have more than one website hosted on my IIS, how do i map to corresponding domains.

Answer (score 6):

Now you need to **create DNS record** for your VM.
See how to do that at http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names

You have got two alternatives here:

1. Create **A record** (DNS name to IP, e.g. subdomain.example.com -> your VM VIP).
   Public Virtual IP (VIP) adress can be found in the VM configuration on manage.windowsazure.com, on the right pane.
2. Create **CNAME record** (DNS name to another DNS name, e.g. subdomain.example.com -> VM-Name.cloudapp.net)
   DNS Name of your VM can also be found in the VM configuration, on the same right pane.

After that, **set appropriate Host Name** (e.g. subdomain.example.com) in IIS site binding so that you can reuse the same port (80) for other sites, binding different Host Names for them.
If you need your site to response for localhost or other DNS name, just add it as *another binding* (see *screenshot*).

[image: *another binding*]

Comment: Also be aware that CNAME record can handle "www" subdomain, but not root domain name. So if you need "example.com" be equal to "www.example.com", you should definitely use A record. But it's a two sided sword: VIP is reset if you deallocate (or remove) your VM, whereas Host Name remains unchanged on reallocation.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Going to do like you said. I'll update you once i succeed.